# Z2JH : Invalid client_id parameter value in hub logs

Tags: oauth-2.0, jupyterhub

We use Z2JH Helm Chart V2.0 and jupyterhub v4.0.0

The following issue is observed intermittently for a few users. After successful OAuth2 authentication, this error log is seen on the hub pod:

```
[D 2023-11-26 10:47:41.771 JupyterHub base:342] Refreshing auth for <username>
[D 2023-11-26 10:47:41.772 JupyterHub provider:420] Validating client id jupyterhub-user-<username>
[W 2023-11-26 10:47:41.776 JupyterHub web:1869] 400 GET /hub/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=jupyterhub-user-<username>&redirect_uri=%2Fuser%2F<username>%2Foauth_callback&response_type=code&state=eyJ1dWlkIjogIjJmZjQ...hYiJ9 (10.2.136.231): Invalid client_id parameter value.
[W 2023-11-26 10:47:41.777 JupyterHub log:191] 400 GET /hub/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=jupyterhub-user-<username>&redirect_uri=%2Fuser%2F<username>%2Foauth_callback&response_type=code&state=[secret] (<username>@10.2.136.231) 18.87ms
[I 2023-11-26 10:47:50.399 JupyterHub log:191] 302 GET /hub/ -> /user/<username>/ (<username>@10.2.136.231) 3.06ms
[D 2023-11-26 10:47:51.192 JupyterHub provider:420] Validating client id jupyterhub-user-<username>
[W 2023-11-26 10:47:51.193 JupyterHub web:1869] 400 GET /hub/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=jupyterhub-user-<username>&redirect_uri=%2Fuser%2F<username>%2Foauth_callback&response_type=code&state=eyJ1dWlkIj...wYmcifQ (10.2.136.231): Invalid client_id parameter value.
[W 2023-11-26 10:47:51.195 JupyterHub log:191] 400 GET /hub/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=jupyterhub-user-<username>&redirect_uri=%2Fuser%2F<username>%2Foauth_callback&response_type=code&state=[secret] (<username>@10.2.136.231) 5.54ms
[D 2023-11-26 10:50:29.937 JupyterHub scopes:690] Argument-based access to /hub/api/users/<username>/activity via users:activity
[D 2023-11-26 10:50:29.942 JupyterHub users:879] Not updating activity for <User(<username> 1/1 running)>: 2023-11-26T06:58:09.623259Z < 2023-11-26T10:47:41.766690Z
[D 2023-11-26 10:50:29.942 JupyterHub users:900] Not updating server activity on <username>/: 2023-11-26T06:58:09.623259Z < 2023-11-26T10:47:41.766690Z
[I 2023-11-26 10:50:29.943 JupyterHub log:191] 200 POST /hub/api/users/<username>/activity (<username>@172.16.2.82) 16.99ms
[D 2023-11-26 10:55:37.672 JupyterHub base:342] Refreshing auth for <username>
```

The user is locked out of their lab. Also on a hub pod restart, the user is able to work with their lab pod for sometime and then the issue shows up again